# Is 'slug away' a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I found *slug away* in a dictionary which says it is a verb. I'm a little bit confused now. I have a similar one *slog away*.Are both of them phrasal verbs having the same meaning?

Comment: To *slog* away implies considerable effort.  To *slug* away does not.  I believe the origin is probably from American baseball, where a big hitter is called a "slugger", or from boxing where a slugger is someone who punches hard.

Answer (score 4):

The preposition *away* ordinarily has a locative sense—approximately, and very generally, "to or at some indefinitely distant point":

> The children put their toys *away*.
>   The soldiers ran *away*.

But when it's used with a verb which doesn't have a clear implication of motion it bears a metaphoric temporal meaning, approximately "for some indefinite time", and usually with some sense of effort or zeal.

> He labored *away* at his homework. = "He labored at his homework for some time".

So *slug away* means approximately "slug continuously for some time". (But what exactly *slug* means will depend on context—it might mean *strike* or *box* or *swing hard at baseballs* or *work doggedly*.)

It's also used with imperatives to give someone permission to perform some action as much or as long as they like:

> A: Is it OK if I read this book?
>   B: Read away.

Comment: Multi-wordness? I've found 'slug away' in more than one dictionary. I'm not going to bother looking for 'read away' (or Bertie Wooster's 'smoke away').

Answer (score 0):

To "slug away" is to hit something again and again, it's a variation of slog.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slog